# ImmutableArray empty collection initializer is not equal to ImmutableArray.Empty in C# 12

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, collection-initializer, c#-12.0

It appears that C# 12's collection initializers don't produce the same result as a ImmutableArray's `Empty` property; for example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ImmutableArray<object> a = ImmutableArray<object>.Empty;
        ImmutableArray<object> b = ImmutableArray<object>.Empty;
        ImmutableArray<object> c = [];
        ImmutableArray<object> d = [];
        
        Console.WriteLine($"a == b: {a == b}");
        Console.WriteLine($"a == c: {a == c}");
        Console.WriteLine($"c == d: {c == d}");
    }
}
```

[Run with .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uKnC7)

> a == b: True
>
> a == c: False
>
> c == d: True

What's the reason for this?

Some notes: On further reflection, I've updated the post, as changing the code to use `ImmutableList<T>` yields `true` in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

[`ImmutableArray<T>.Equals`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray_1.Minimal.cs#L320) compares underlying arrays:

```
public override bool Equals([NotNullWhen(true)] object? obj)
{
    return obj is IImmutableArray other && this.array == other.Array;
}
public bool Equals(ImmutableArray<T> other)
{
    return this.array == other.array;
}
```

And all instances of `ImmutableArray<object>.Empty` will point to the same array and all instances of `ImmutableArray<object> _ = [];` will point to the same array but those would be 2 different empty arrays.

**Details**

While [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/collection-expressions#empty-collection-literal) explicitly mentions that:

> The empty collection expression is permitted to be a singleton if used to construct a final collection value that is known to not be mutable.

And `ImmutableArray<T>` having  [create method proxied with `CollectionBuilderAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/collection-expressions#create-methods)([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray_1.cs#L14)) to [`ImmutableArray.Create`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray.cs#L90):

> The method must have a single parameter of type `System.ReadOnlySpan<E>`, passed by value,

```
[CollectionBuilder(typeof(ImmutableArray), nameof(ImmutableArray.Create))]
public readonly partial struct ImmutableArray<T> :
```

```
public static ImmutableArray<T> Create<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> items)
{
    if (items.IsEmpty)
    {
        return ImmutableArray<T>.Empty;
    }

    T[] array = items.ToArray();
    return new ImmutableArray<T>(array);
}
```

And [`ImmutableArray<T>.Empty` is](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/libraries/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray_1.Minimal.cs#L44):

```
#pragma warning disable CA1825
// Array.Empty<T>() doesn't exist in all configurations
// Switching to Array.Empty also has a non-negligible impact on the working set memory
public static readonly ImmutableArray<T> Empty = new ImmutableArray<T>(new T[0]);
#pragma warning restore CA1825
```

But as you can see [in the actual decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoBAGABAlAOgGEB7AG3IFMBjAFylJgGdCBJMMAVzomGoDcmXCNFjx4zB269+VAIIAnRRACeAHlLAAVrToA+XBFwBeXNJ59qSlRq276+wgFEwABzqqhGC7OvK1TR09Q2BTc05LORtA+xCXd09vXysFALtgx1wacIBtAF1kyL802yCHA1wAEzzC4QlcTAIATgAKABIAImMTM1BcAG8evoBfToBKbxaO7tMzGhBB4eyxyaaUNq6c3urFge2zKtXvIA===) of empty collection expression results in:

```
ImmutableCollectionsMarshal.AsImmutableArray(Array.Empty<object>())
```

Which just creates a new `ImmutableArray`:

```
public static ImmutableArray<T> AsImmutableArray<T>(T[]? array)
{
   return new(array);
}
```

So `ImmutableArray<object>.Empty` and `ImmutableArray<object> c = []` will point to different locations in memory (but they will be the same for the same expressions used). I.e. all `ImmutableArray<object>.Empty` will be equal and all `ImmutableArray<object> _ = []` will be equal but not equal to each other. Note that in general it does not break any guarantees made by specification (since it is not even guaranteed to be a singleton).

Submitted issue [@gitub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95765)

Comment: Do you know how the compiler decides to use ImmutableCollectionsMarshal.AsImmutableArray?

Comment: @MichaelLiu no idea. Asked at github.

Comment: Thanks for submitting this on GitHub. Good to see there's some activity around it :)